# White screen after building my electron-vue app for production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, vue-router, electron-builder

I am building an electron-vue app with multiple windows, I am using vue-router.

The app works well when running from Visual Studio Code terminal (dev mode), but after building it for production I am getting a white screen.

Here is my code

public/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
  <title>EmaFlow Work Sessiong Tracker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but statement-ts doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
      continue.</strong>
  </noscript>

  <div id="app" class="h-100"></div>

  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>

</html>
```

src/App.vue

```xml
<template>
  <div id="app" class="h-100">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

src/router.ts

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import LoginWindow from '@/views/LoginWindow.vue';
import MainWindow from '@/views/MainWindow.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginWindow,
    },
    {
      path: '/main',
      name: 'main',
      component: MainWindow,
    },
  ],
});
```

src/main.ts

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import VueTimers from 'vue-timers'

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

Vue.use(VueTimers)

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');

import $ from 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js';
```

src/background.ts

```js
'use strict'
    
import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Event } from 'electron'
import {
  createProtocol,
  installVueDevtools
} from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([{ scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }])

const appWindows: BrowserWindow[] = [];

function createWindow(slug: string, options?: object) {
  const defaultOptions = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  };
  const windowOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);
  const window = new BrowserWindow(windowOptions);
  appWindows.push(window);

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    window.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL as string + '/#' + slug);
    window.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    window.loadURL('app://./index.html' + '/#' + slug);
  }

  window.on('closed', () => {
    appWindows.splice(appWindows.indexOf(window), 1);
  });
}

function createLoginWindow() {
  createWindow('/', {
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    resizable: isDevelopment,
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installVueDevtools();
    } catch (e) {
      // console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString());
    }
  }

  createLoginWindow();
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (appWindows.length === 0) {
    createLoginWindow();
  }
})

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

ipcMain.on('open-window', (e: Event, arg: WindowParams) => {
  createWindow(arg.route, arg.options);
});

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', data => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit()
    })
  }
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "emaflow-worksession-tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "howler": "^2.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.15",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-timers": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.12.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.0",
    "electron": "^5.0.11",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

On app launch, a login window will be shown, on success login, the login window will close and open another window.

To open a window, in `background.ts` I created the function `createWindow` which takes the router path as the first parameter. To create the login window for example I call `createWindow('/', options)` and to create the main app window after successful login I write `createWindow('/main', options)`.

I think my problem is in `window.loadUrl` inside `createWindow` in `background.ts`, but I am not sure what the correct url should be for production mode.

please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: i've seen this sort of issue when a js error will stop further js from evaluation.  You can try removing your script tag from your index.html just to see if the login page gets created.  Also helpful for this type of issue is to openDevTools in your prod version and see the errors in console.

Comment: @anwar why do you have custom protocol ('app') ?. Check if loadURL function supports custom protocol?

Comment: I removed script tag from index.html, and imported jquery in main.ts instead. I opened dev tools in prod version, no errors in console but still getting the white screen, it does not load the index.html, I don't see the contents of index.html in dev tools, I just see empty body. Regarding the app protocol, honestly I don't know what is it, I copied these lines of code from some boilerplate or tutorial. If I remove these lines of code, I get errors like  'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME app://./js/app.7cbb0157.js:1' in the console, looks like this protocol is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I could make `window.loadUrl` working for the production version as follows:

```
createProtocol('app');
window.loadURL(formatUrl({
   pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
   protocol: 'file',
   slashes: true
}));
```

The above code is working but it only opens the login window which has the path '/' in the vue-router routes list.

To open a window for another route like '/main' I tried to append a hash and the route to the pathname like this:

```
window.loadURL(formatUrl({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html#', slug),
  protocol: 'file',
  slashes: true
}));
```

but it did not work and on dev tools network tab I see this error:

Name: index.html%23/ Status: (blocked:other)

please advice

EDIT: all worked after adding the `hash` property to the options object passed to `formatUrl` instead of appending to the `pathname` manually:

```
window.loadURL(formatUrl({
   pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
   protocol: 'file',
   slashes: true,
   hash: slug
}));
```

Comment: Just use the `path.join` method without `formatUrl` because formatUrl encodes your given url but you need the # as # and not html encoded form.

Answer (score 1):

For folks that are looking for their white-screen solution. Electron doesn't work with the history mode of your router from the box. Switch router mode to hash mode or check how to make friendship with history mode in electron documentation.